# Better Promise aproach when needs to treat errors and continue with the Promise flow

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I need the follow logic in my function:

1. Using passport to log in with facebook, i call the method to retrieve the user with the facebook id.
2. If user exists, done!
3. Else i call the method to retrieve the user with the email.
4. If user exists, i need to update the user with the facebook id and it's done!
5. Else if user doesn't exists, i need to create his account with email and facebook id.

In java, for example, it would be like this:

```
try {
  User user = userService.findByFacebookAccount(id);
  if(user != null) {
    done(user);
  } else {
    user = userService.findByEmail(email);
    if(user != null) {
      user.setFacebookAccount(id);
      if(userService.update(user)) {
        done(user); // Update with success
      } else {
        throws new Exception();
      }
    } else {
      user = userService.createByFacebookAccount(name, email, facebook_id);
      if(user != null) {
        done(user);
      } else {
        throws new Exception();
      }
    }
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  done(e);
}
```

How can i organize that to do with Promises ?
I did as follow using bluebird promises:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  var profileInfos = profile._json;
  userService.findByFacebookAccount(profileInfos.id).then(function(user) {
    done(null, user);                                  
  }).error(function(e) {
    return userService.findByEmail(profileInfos.email);
  }).then(function(user) {            
    user.set('facebook_account', profileInfos.id);
    return userService.update(user, ['facebook_account']);
  }).then(function(user) {
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(e) {        
    return userService.createByFacebookAccount(profileInfos.name, profileInfos.gender, profileInfos.username, profileInfos.email, profileInfos.id);
  }).then(function(user) {
    done(null, user);                    
  }).catch(function(e) {
    done(null);
  });
}
```

I think it's wrong because when "return userService.update(user, ['facebook_account']);" is rejected i need to catch the error and returns error and don't create the user.

What is the best way to transform from sync logic to promise ?

Comment: What do you mean *wrong*? What went wrong? Also since all you want to do is call done() each time you don't have to return then like that. This will simplify the number of then and error functions chained.

Comment: After the first and second "then" i have an "error" that will treat errors from "findByEmail" and "Update" and creates the user, but i need to create the user only if findByEmail is rejected.

Can you answer the question simplifying this promises ?

Comment: If the second error is dependent on the promise result above it then you might have to nest them instead. An error should catch everything above it which can confuse transmuting the promises.

Comment: Your catch function is missing a parameter

Comment: It's catching any generic error: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-handler---promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix promises and callbacks, unless you are looking to make an callback api but want to use promises internally (in that case use `.nodeify`). Also don't swallow errors and force the user to check return value.

```
function doIt(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  var profileInfos = profile._json;
  return userService.findByFacebookAccount(profileInfos.id).then(function(user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }
    return userService.findByEmail(profileInfos.email).then(function(user) {
      if (user != null) {
        user.setFacebookAccount(id))
        return userService.update(user).then(function(updated) {
          // userService should actually just throw the error in the first place and not
          // swallow it and return false, which is making code much uglier than it needs to be here
          if (!updated) throw new Error();
          return user;
        });
      } else {
        return userService.createByFacebookAccount(name, email, facebook_id).then(function(user) {
          if (user != null) return user;
          throw new Error();
        })
      }
    })                                
  }).nodeify(done);
}
```

Usage is:

```
doIt(...)
.then(function(user) {

})
.catch(function(error){

});
```

Since we used `.nodeify()`, callback interface is supported as well:

```
doIt(..., function(err, user) {

});
```

---

If the services were using exceptions instead of returning null/false in case of error, it could be slightly cleaner:

```
function doIt(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  var profileInfos = profile._json;
  return userService.findByFacebookAccount(profileInfos.id).then(function(user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }
    return userService.findByEmail(profileInfos.email).then(function(user) {
      if (user != null) {
        user.setFacebookAccount(id))
        return userService.update(user).thenReturn(user);
      } else {
        return userService.createByFacebookAccount(name, email, facebook_id)
      }
    })                                
  }).nodeify(done);
}
```